# .Net Core Localization not working on startup

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asp.net-core

I'have a persistent problem with my Localization. Tried various of solutions provided online, but none answered my problem.

The problem is that my Localization (ViewLocalization) isn't loaded on startup on production server. When i hit F5, the same page reloads with Localization.

On my development machine, when i test locally, everything works fine. With this machine, i push to VSTS (git) and triggeres my Azure which builds and deploys the app.

**Possible causes:**

1. Doesn't find resources? Seems odd, because after F5 the localization works ok
2. IIS issue? No, loads localization perfectly locally.
3. Faulty Startup.cs? looks ok i guess:

   ```
       public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
       {
          // code omitted
       }
       public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {


           services.AddMvc(config =>
           {

               config.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new ScrubbingModelBinderProvider());
           }).AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix).AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(); ;

           services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
           {
               var supportedCultures = new[] {
               new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
               new CultureInfo("nl-NL")

           };
               opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("nl-NL");
               opts.FallBackToParentCultures = false;
               opts.FallBackToParentUICultures = false;
               opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
               opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
               opts.RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider> {
                   new CookieRequestCultureProvider { CookieName = "_cultureFrigroAircoWebApp" },
                   new AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider { } };
           });

           services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");

           // Add application services.
           // Services omitted

       }
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
       {


           loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
           loggerFactory.AddDebug();

           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
               app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
               app.UseBrowserLink();
           }
           else
           {

               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Shared/Error");
           }

           var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();

           app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

           app.UseIdentity();
           app.UseSession();          
           app.UseStaticFiles();       

          // routes omitted

       }
   ```
4. Viewlocalizer not injected in startup? Can't seem to understand why it wouldn't work... I use "@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer" in _ViewImports.cshtml.
5. Cookie not set when loading the page for the first time? I don't think it is this problem. Because when someone on the same network tries the webapp, it works ok (when someone has tried before)
6. My web.config:

```html
    <globalization culture="auto:nl-NL" uiCulture="auto:nl-NL" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

I use .NET Core:

```
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
```

Has anyone an idea where i go wrong? Or some thought in the right direction?

Thanks for YOUR time!

Samuel

Comment: ``i push to VSTS (git) and triggeres my Azure which builds and deploys the app`` Please try to deploy your app to a new Azure web site directly and check if it works well.

Comment: Seems to work at this moment. Didn't see any of my localization keys. I'll get back here with a definitive answer.

Comment: Ok, not solved. Still have the issue that my localization strings aren't loaded on first run. I have it on Both my master and development branch...